# Start profiling part way through a programs run

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling

### Background

I'm attempting to profile a part of a program which is difficult to separate out for profiling purposes (in the first instance I just want to find bottlenecks in the real running program). However, the program has a significant initial load phase, the second that phase is over I reset the collected results; throwing all that data away. I then start the real profiling.

The profiling of the initial load phase significantly slows it down and I'm looking to avoid that as I throw that data away anyway.

I'm using the standard Netbeans profiler.

I looked into profiling points; however, they seem to reset the results, take snapshots etc rather than turning the profiling on and off.

### Question

Is it possible to start the collection of profiling data part way through a running program, or pause the collection of results before restarting?

Answer (score 0):

With VisualVM it is trivial to start profiling at any point. Also, the *Sampler*, as opposed to *Profiler*, uses a lightweight strategy to gain the data. It starts and stops instantly, introducing almost no overhead to the running application.

Although the *Profiler* is supposed to be more accurate, my actual findings are the opposite. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option "Reset collected results" just before you want to start profiling. This can also be done when some code is hit with a profiling point. When you don't want to lose the previous results a snapshot can be triggered with another profiling point.

Pausing profiling can only performed manually with the pause button.

Comment: I'm more trying to avoid the initial status being a achingly low. So collecting the results then throwing them away doesn't help me unfortunately